# window.getSelection() to select text only within class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `contenteditable=true` div, where user enters his feedback and I want to allow him change the text color of selected text written in div when user clicks on colorpalate.

I have full code to do my task of changing the color of selected text with user desired color.
But...
Everthing else on the page can be selected and changed its colour too, which I want to prevent. I want to allow change the colour only for class="comment".

Just can't understand how to do that with below code.

`if (window.getSelection) { // all browsers, except IE before version 9
           var selectionRange = window.getSelection (); 
                if (selectionRange.isCollapsed) {
                    alert ("Please select some content first!");
                }
                else { 
                      //do the stuff
                     }
       }`

Thanks for help

Comment: have you looked into jQuerys' `wrap` or `wrapInner` methods? You can find them here: http://devdocs.io/jquery/wrap | http://devdocs.io/jquery/wrapinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED : to include highlight functionality**

Here's the jsFiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nzk9hfg9/3/)

```
$("#highlight").click(function(){
    var flag = 0;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; i++) {
        var $sNode = $(sel.getRangeAt(i).startContainer.parentNode);
        var $eNode = $(sel.getRangeAt(i).endContainer.parentNode);
        if ($sNode.prop("class") == "comment" && $eNode.prop("class") == "comment"){
            $sNode.html($sNode.html().replace(sel,"<span class='selectedText'>"+ sel + "</span>"));
        }
    }
});
```

Will only highlight if text is selected from `comment` class div only

Comment: Dear Himanshu, can you modify code for dyanamic class being created by other plugin but present in DOM

Comment: @user3525233 which dynamic class? "comment" or "selectedText" in above ex?

Comment: Dear Himanshu, I am trying to use emojiarea plugin where it creates a class name "emoji-wysiwyg-editor" when applied to textarea. Now everything else works fine. Your code also works perfectly detecting other classes but not this one. Any help will be great !!

Comment: could you post the generated html?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/nzk9hfg9/5/ this is new fiddle. Just set `highLightClass` to the name of the class you want to apply selection.

Comment: Dear Himanshu, Thanks for efforts.. But I noticed the code does not work under this situation`<div class="comment" contenteditable="true">Here <b>goes some text</b></div>` . if we select the text within <b> and </b> highlight doesnot happen. Pls suggest how we can still highlight the text.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu,your code help me put in right direction to do what I wanted.

Comment: How can you set this to pure JS?

Comment: it works but how about if the div has more elements inside it?